# error: expected primary-expression before '&&' token

Tags: c++

```
class ABC{
public: 

    ABC& operater=(ABC &&);  
};
```

GCC complains:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '&&' token
[build]      ABC& operater=(ABC &&);
```

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `operator`.

`operater=` should be `operator=`.

Comment: Oh My God! Thank you so much.